# Angular7 component view collapsing on data manipulation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am experiencing the strangest issue. I do have a component that's style is controlled by some object it's handling. As the object is manipulated (by some inner component click), the whole view collapses to a height of 0.

I have tried to apply the view changes via ngStyle, ngClass, plain ol'javascript - but nothing ever worked. Second strange thing - handling outer component's component styles is perfectly working.

**Object**

```
const valueMap = {
  width: '100%',
  ...
}
```

**Pseudo Component Tree**

```
<component-a>
  <component-b [ngStyle]="{'width': valueMap.width} [valueMap]="valueMap">
    <div (click)="changePosition()">Button</div>
  </component-b>
</component-a>
```

**Method**

```
changePosition() {
  this.valueMap.width = this.valueMap.width==='100%' ? '50%' : '100%';
}
```

I would really expect the component-b to collapse to a width of 50%, but not having the height collapse to zero. I can see in the code, that as I click the button the style is applied to the element - and if in Chrome DevTools I deactivate the applied style and activate it again, it is showing properly. Never had something like this. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance. André

Comment: you should use two-way binding [(valueMap)]="valueMap".. I can't see the other parts of your code, but I guess you should set display:block to component-b and the same for comp-a if you want to use that width as relative.

Comment: I see your point, but two-way binding doesn't help, as component-b is not directly capable of editing itself, like a input field or something.

Comment: In you pseudo-component tree, ngStyle is a little bit strange. Does it reflect exactly the way you're using it in your code?

Comment: Inside `component-b` considering `valueMap` as input parameter

    `@Input() valueMap: any; `   

    


Put ngStyle in component-b html main wrapper div

    `<div [ngStyle]="{width: valueMap.width}"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your problem. altough i couldnt get the error you seem to be having, i think i can see the issue at hand:

from your html

```html
<component-a>
  <component-b [ngStyle]="{width: 'valueMap.width'} [valueMap]="valueMap">
    <div (click)="changePosition()">Button</div>
  </component-b>
</component-a>
```

i could get, that your "valueMap" is an Input() within component-b.
so i did that on my end aswell and declared valuemap on the outermost component (the one using component a and b)

i recreated your html and found parsing errors and whatnot until i realized something:

```html
  <app-collapse-on-click>
    <app-collapse-child [ngStyle]="{'width': valueMap.width, 'background-color': 'rebeccapurple'}" [valueMap]="valueMap">
      <div><button (click)="changePosition()">Button</button></div>
    </app-collapse-child>
  </app-collapse-on-click>
```

when using ngStyle, the style is interpreted as an object. meaning, in your case you need to remove the ' arround valueMap.width and add them to width.

i added the background color to get a visual result other than just the style html.

hope that somehow helps.

regards

Alan

Comment: You are right, but that was just me typing in here wrong. Of course I don't have quotes around the valueMap.width value. Sorry, stupid me.

Comment: ok this is weird. on my end everything was working perfectly fine. height didnt change whatsoever. did you put quotes arround width?